# NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: appsettings.json

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

Im getting this error on Team Services release. I suspected that this error occours because im generating a zipped artifact.

The MSBuild configuration:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

Then in my Release im trying to replace the `appsettings.json` variables:

[image: replace file]

So the artifact is a zip file and problably because this the release management is not finding the appsettings.json file. But what is the way to deal with it?  Build an artifact not zipped?

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
**/appsettings.json
```

The json file is buried down in a long deep path based on the location of the agent and how MSBuild packages it up...it's not at the "root".

For example, my json file was in this folder within the WebApp.zip file:

> WebApp.zip\Content\C_C\Build\Agent\agent_work\3\s\CrmsAngularPOC\obj\Release\netcoreapp1.1\PubTmp\Out

Comment: it works for Azure DevOps, Azure App Service Deploy task, too.

Comment: Outstanding this saved me loads of time. Thanks a million.

Comment: What is the syntax for replacing a json value? I have read the documentation I cannot get it right. This is what I've been trying.

ConnectionStrings.MyDbConnectionString :"Server=....."

The json is like this.

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnectionString ": "Server=.."
  },
  .....,
 ......
}

Answer (score 2):

if your source folder is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_SOURCE_FOLDER_/artifacts

you can use "appsettings.json"

but if your source folder is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_SOURCE_FOLDER_

you can use "**/appsettings.json"

Answer (score -1):

You should use JSONPath expressions to specify variable(s) you want to substitute for Json variable substitution option.

Detail usage of **JSON variable substitution** as below:

> Provide new line separated list of JSON files to substitute the
>   variable values. Files names are to be provided relative to the root
>   folder.  To substitute JSON variables that are nested or hierarchical,
>   specify them using JSONPath expressions.
>
> For example, to replace the value of ‘`ConnectionString`’ in the
>   sample below, you need to define a variable as
>   ‘Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString’ in the build/release
>   definition (or release definition’s environment).
>
> ```
> {
>   "Data": {
>     "DefaultConnection": {
>       "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Variable Substitution is run after configuration transforms.
>
> Note: Build/Release’s system definition variables are excluded in
>   substitution

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand this line `Provide new line separated list of JSON files to substitute the variable values. ` Here i understant that i need to put the name of the json file that i want to replace variables, in case appsettings.json file, and not the variables itself.

Comment: For the above example, it means you should add `Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString` in variables Tab. And **JSON variables substitution** in Azure App Service Deploy task, you should set as you did(`appsettings.json`).

Comment: yes, thats the problem, when i did it i got an error saying that ´NO JSON file matched with specific pattern: appsettings.json´. My doubt is if its because the appsettings.json is inside a zipfile.

Comment: @ggui The similar issue has been solved (github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4637), check whether it works fine for you.